# Solution of a linear stochastic equation with multiplicative noise in front of the derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

In the context of physics, I obtained a stochastic PDE with Stratonovich convention:
$$(a + \tilde A(t))\dfrac{d\vec x}{dt} = b\vec x + \tilde C(t)$$

Where the matrix $\tilde A$ and $\tilde C$ are white noise random processes with 0 average:
$$\langle\tilde A(t)\tilde A(t') \rangle=\langle\tilde B(t)\tilde B(t') \rangle=\delta(t - t')$$
and $a$ and $b$ simple constant (hopefully :))! I'm a bit confused as how to proceed to solve this equation especially since dividing by $\tilde A$ does not feel right at all.

Comment: Did you mean $C$ is white noise?

Comment: also by white noise, do you mean the derivative of Brownian motion $dB/dt$? (There are other more general notions of white noise).

Comment: can you add any references to read more about the context?

Comment: There are many articles on studying multiplicative noise eg. "Stochastic heat equations with general multiplicative Gaussian noises: Hölder continuity and intermittency" https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.2618

Comment: But the problem with your equation is that it is ill-posed because you are multiplying two distributions $A\cdot dx/dt.$ (the dx/dt inherits the regularity of the white-noise C from the RHS).

Comment: @ThomasKojar It is ill posed even when we say that it is coming from a discretized equation with stratonovich convention?

Comment: As for the context, I was trying to study an ensemble of particles with random viscosity and random noise on a lattice, in spatial and time fourier space... I don't believe it was studied before

Comment: For what it's worst, it is coming from a second order differential equation: $m\dfrac{d^2x}{dt} + (a + \tilde A)\dfrac{dx}{dt} = bx + \tilde C$. It might be easier to deal with this equation?

Comment: any details please add them in your post. For example, add a reference to what you mean by "white noise" mathematically. If you mean $dB_t$ (derivative of BM) then this equation is ill-posed because you cannot multiply distributions together.

Comment: There is no second derivative because Brownian motion is nowhere differentiable and $x_t$ will inherit the regularity of BM if by white noise you mean derivative of BM.

Comment: Perhaps this better fits in https://physics.stackexchange.com/, to help you formulate a well-posed equation from your particular physics context. Then you can return here and we can discuss.